# Is it possible to edit .ipa file and link new framework/library?

Tags: xcode, dll, frameworks, ipa

I need to edit the ipa file and link new framework/library to the application, without Xcode. I don't have the source code of the application.
Is it possible do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to edit the ipa file using optool successfully. Its successfully loads the library at runtime.